# Terraform Error: Extraneous label for module when running terraform init

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax-error, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am getting this error when I run terraform init:

```
Error: Extraneous label for module

  on rds.tf line 22, in module "rds" "app":
  22: module "rds" "app" {

Only 1 labels (name) are expected for module blocks.
```

I have a two modules created "rds" and "app" which I am both referencing when creating a db instance:

```
# PostgreSQL RDS App Instance
module "rds" "app" {
```

How doI fix this error?

Comment: module "module_name" {} should be syntax , i dont think you can call module with two names , if you want to call the module twice call them seperately module "rds" {} and module "app" {}

Answer (score 0):

If using TF 0.13, another option would be to use a single module with a count set to 2 and then a count.index to fetch the specific name for that iteration from a predefined list [] variable.

https://blog.ktz.me/terraform-0-13-count-modules/